# Javascript, loading cookies having an unexpected delay

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on javascript with a basic login logout system. I have a login page that loads when you request a login, and on successful entry of the information stores your username as a cookie, using document.cookie = "user=USERNAME". Then the page uses window.href to load the the home page.

However, the cookie isn't recognized. When I alert(document.cookie) it shows me no text. And then, when I click a button for another page within the localhost domain (different from home or login), the cookie magically appears! It then also shows up on the home page, and all other pages till I logout.

My login code is

```
    function login() {
    var user = document.getElementById("userL");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "u="+user.value,
        success: function(msg) {
            var pass = document.getElementById("passL").value;
            if (msg === pass && !(msg === "")) {
                document.cookie = "user="+user.value;
                alert(document.cookie);
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/Hometube/Tube.html";                  
            } else {
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Invalid User or Pass";
            }
        }
    })      
}
```

To check a cookie on a different page I simply split the document.cookie. If that is needed to answer the question I'll put it up too. But I can't see any cookie, let alone split it so if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

---

I've tried setting a delay on the function before loading a new page, but that didn't help. I've also checked, the cookie is definitely stored on the login page. But it vanishes for any page I redirect to. Refreshing doesn't bring it back. But, going to a new page on the localhost domain and coming back makes the cookie appear.

Comment: You're most probably looking at an `HttpOnly` cookie. If so, you won't have access to it using JavaScript.

Comment: ^ this only applies if you previously set the cookie on the server side

Comment: Well, if I was then wouldn't I always be not allowed to access the cookie? Currently just a user-triggered page change lets javascript access the cookie.